# How to modify all rows of duplicates values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame df with ~250 000 rows, and ~50 columns.
In a column there are duplicates values, like these (simplified) :

```
'A'     'B'
jean    626
michel  950
john    382      
john    356    <-- duplicate value
boris   315
clara   886
george  619
edmund  365
edmund  523    <-- duplicate value
edmund  703    <-- duplicate value
tony    416
edgard  108
tom     374
fanny   784
lucy    660
paul    728
rebecca 919
rebecca 131    <-- duplicate value
roger   924
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column 'C', where :
- each time I found an unique value in 'A', the value in 'C' is the same as in 'B'
- each time I found a duplicate value in 'A', the corresponding value in 'C' is the same as the first value of the duplicates group.
The number of duplicates in a group could by > 20.

The result should be  :

```
'A'     'B' 'C'
jean    626 626
michel  950 950      
john    382 382     
john    356 382     
max     315 315
clara   886 886
george  619 619
edmund  365 365
edmund  523 365
edmund  703 365
tony    416 416
edgard  108 108
tom     374 374
fanny   784 784
lucy    660 660
paul    728 728
rebecca 919 919
rebecca 131 919
roger   924 924
```

I’ve tried the following code :

```
def myfunc(group):
    group['C'][group['C']==0]=group['B'][0]
    return group
df=df.groupby('A').apply(myfunc)
```

This works but it takes a very, very long time to exec (~600 sec.). 
Any idea to improve this ? Another solution to do this with more efficiency ?

Comment: Is the initial order of your 'A' column that important? I'm trying to see if doing first `df = df.sort_values(by='A')` is a big problem or not.
Otherwise, are your duplicates already grouped like in your example? Or can you something like ['john', 'john', 'notjohn', 'john']?

Comment: The initial order of 'A' is not important. You can sort df by 'A'.

Comment: Nevermind, I had worked out a solution but that's more complicated and longer than @DSM's transform option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input doesn't quite match your output (boris vs. max, e.g.), but if I understand what you're after, you can use `.transform("first")`:

```
In [27]: df["C"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].transform("first")

In [28]: df.head(10)
Out[28]: 
         A    B    C
0    jean0  626  626
1  michel0  950  950
2    john0  382  382
3    john0  356  382
4   boris0  315  315
5   clara0  886  886
6  george0  619  619
7  edmund0  365  365
8  edmund0  523  365
9  edmund0  703  365

In [29]: len(df)
Out[29]: 249983
```

which takes only a few seconds for me.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. 0,53s vs 660s with my prévious "solution". This is a great improvment ! I need to explore and experiment the transform() method.